# ¿Por que cada rama de Git en GitHub tiene un origin?

Tags: git, github

Cuando creo varias ramas, usualmente uso *VSCode* al hacer las ramas,  me doy cuenta que existen una versión *origin*, ¿Qué se hace con eso? ¿a cual le hago *push*? ¿a cual le hago *pull*? ¿Qué diferencia tiene una rama *origin* y una rama sin *origin*? ¿Qué ventajas me trae el tener *origin*? ¿puedo hacer algo con eso?

Comment: Te recomendaría que te familiarizases con la línea de comandos de git. Aunque VSCode gestiona bastante bien el tema de git; al usar el entorno gráfico pierdes el control de lo que realmente estás haciendo.

Comment: @ÓscarNovás Si, precisamente esta pregunta la hice porque estoy creando una guía (para mi y quien lo necesite) de Git (con la linea de comandos) y GitHub: [Github guía],(https://gist.github.com/Relibarion/5f062096fa933731b97960af387ed0fa). Al estar usando VSCode no me he documentado mas allá de Git.

Answer (score 2):

En Git, `origin` es un nombre abreviado para el repositorio remoto desde el que se clonó originalmente un proyecto. Más precisamente, se usa en lugar de la URL del repositorio original y, por lo tanto, hace que la referencia sea mucho más fácil.

**Subir y bajar cambios a un repositorio remoto:**

Una vez disponemos de un respositorio local y uno remoto en los que trabajar, se pueden subir los cambios que hemos hecho en nuestro repositorio local a nuestro repositorio remoto. También podmos mantener nuestro repositorio actualizado con cambios que puedan haber hecho otros usuarios.

**Subir cambios al repositorio remoto:** `git push`

Para ello, una vez hemos hecho un git commit, debemos usar el comando `git push`:

`$ git push origin <branch>`

Donde `<branch>` es la rama que queremos subir al repositorio remoto. Ejemplo:

`$ git push origin master`

**Bajar cambios del repositorio remoto:** `git pull`

Imaginemos ahora que queremos actualizar nuestro repositorio local con los posibles cambios que se hayan podido producir en el repositorio remoto. Si trabajamos en un mismo repositorio con más gente, este es un paso imprescindible para mantener nuestra copia local del repositorio al día. De hecho, si existen cambios en el repositorio remoto, Git no nos dejará subir cambios al repositorio hasta que hayamos descargado la versión más reciente y la hayamos fusionado con nuestra versión local. La forma más sencilla de actualizar el repositorio local es mediante el comando `git pull`:

`$ git pull`